# What is a word to describe a person who lies to achieve a personal goals?

Tags: single-word-requests

I heard a news anchor use a word to describe Donald Trump as someone who lies to accomplish, achieve personal gain.

Comment: There are several words that could fit that description, and without some context, what you heard will remain a mystery.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if you were being sarcastic are not but, thank you anyway. The word I was looking for and found was subterfuge.

Answer (score 3):

"Deceitful," "dissembling," or "perfidious" could work here within the right context.

From Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/):

Deceitful: having a tendency or disposition to deceive or give false impressions.

Dissembling: to put on a false appearance : conceal facts, intentions, or feelings under some pretense.

Perfidy: the quality or state of being faithless or disloyal.

Comment: Also look at disingenuous and mendacious.